# Title of navbar dropdown won't change when item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched through all of the questions related to this that I can find and I just can't seem to make the text change.

Here is the dropdown in question:

Marketsource

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


    <!--First Dropdown - This needs to be fixed. Should change the text when clicked to the store that was selected.-->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span id="StoreType">Store Type</span></a>
      <div id="dropdownStore" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="100" onclick="setStoreType(100);"  >Best Buy</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="101" onclick="setStoreType(101);"  >Office Deopt</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="102" onclick="setStoreType(102);"  >Office Max</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="103" onclick="setStoreType(103);"  >Staples</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="104" onclick="setStoreType(104);"  >Costco</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

I included the part for the navbar because the way I have it setup currently doesn't seem to quite match any of the examples I have seen.

Javascript that I have right now (I've gone through quite a few variations on something similar):

```
//Dropdown toggle
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
$(this).closest('.dropdown-item').children('a').text($(this).text())
});
```

Can someone assist me with my issue? It's not super important but it's something that would give this webapp a little more responsiveness.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I realize it's been a little bit since I asked this, but I still haven't been able to get it to work. I put the two files that are needed into a Github Gist here:
JS: https://gist.github.com/ChristopherBare/bd29ba9bc4ffea9953c3039acc03f81d 
HTML: https://gist.github.com/ChristopherBare/b2770b00881b978af3b666ba67c0e4b1

I don't know whats going on with it. If someone can just look over the files and tell me where I went wrong, that would help tremendously.

P.S. There are a couple functions in the JS that don't really do anything yet because they aren't done. So just ignore that for now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown-item').children('a').text($(this).text());
```

and th html is like:

```
<div id="dropdownStore" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
  <a class="dropdown-item" id="100" onclick="setStoreType(100);"  >Best Buy</a>
```

here `.dropdown-item` is under `.dropdown-menu` and you are using `closest()` selector, which search for the DOM upwards. Instead of `closest` try `find()` and also remove `.children('a')` as `.dropdown-item` is itself an anchor.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: I have implemented the changes and it still isn't changing. this is what I've changed it to:

`//Dropdown toggle
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-item').text($(this).text())
});`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you could do it simply without that extra setStoreType function.(though I am not sure what you are trying to do with that function so i skipped it.)

If you wanted to the id as the store type and not the text inside the link I can add that later.

```js
//Dropdown toggle
/*
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
$(this).closest('.dropdown-item').children('a').text($(this).text())
});
*/

function setStoreType(){
  
}

//Dropdown toggle
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function(){
 $("#StoreType").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.dropdown-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


    <!--First Dropdown - This needs to be fixed. Should change the text when clicked to the store that was selected.-->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span id="StoreType">Store Type</span></a>
      <div id="dropdownStore" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="100">Best Buy</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="101">Office Deopt</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="102">Office Max</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="103">Staples</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="104">Costco</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: I feel like we are getting closer. All I want is for the text on the button to change to what is clicked in the dropdown. I also realized I hadn't imported jQuery. I did all of that and inserted what you have there. It just won't change. I cant figure out why.

Comment: The setStoreType() function is to set the text in the modal for a different thing.

Comment: If you click the text in my example it will change the text of the top item there.

Comment: Right, and it does when I click it on here. But I put it into my code and the text doesn't change. I thought it was because I didn't have jQuery imported. But that wasn't it. I even tried putting it inline and that still didn't help.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in the console? Can you do a simple console.log("Some Text"); inside the on click function to see if javascript is even running?

Comment: I added a console.log("it ran"); and it did nothing.

Comment: Sot it's clear that it just never gets to the JS. But I can't see why, all of my other JS runs fine.

Comment: Your Js is stopping somewhere, so do the  console.log("it ran"); at different parts of your page, like 4 places, and change the text for each one. Then look at the console do see where the JS stopped. From there I can help because the problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found an answer to this issue. I have posted some github gists so that all of the code is there. It is something to do with jQuery not working properly, or possibly the way that I have my dropdown formatted?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please review the guidlines on answering questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)